# What's the rule for training multiple levels of a game using DQNs?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to create benchmarks for a variety of games that have 5 levels each. The goal is to train a model to convergence on 3 levels first, and then measure the learning curves on the remaining 2 levels.

Is there a general rule for how models should be trained on multiple levels? Should the training be done on one level after another?

Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are able to train for `N` levels in total (within the time constraints you may have).

I would **not recommend** the following setup:

1. Train `N / 3` times on the first level
2. Train `N / 3` times on the second level
3. Train `N / 3` times on the second level

The risk with such a setup is that you first learn to play well on the first level, then forget everything you learned and "overfit" to the second level, and then forget again and overfit to the third level.

---

You'll want to make sure that you consistently keep a nice mix of levels throughout the entire training process, because the goal ultimately is to generalize and perform well on the (unseen) levels 4 and 5.

To do this, I'd recommend one of the following setups:

1. Train once on the first level
2. Train once on the second level
3. Train once on the third level
4. Repeat from step one again, untill you've trained the maximum `N` times

Alternatively:

1. Randomly select one of the first three levels to train.
2. Repeat until `N` times trained.

---

It may be possible to do even better with more sophisticated strategies. For example, you could try tracking your average performance per level over the last `X` times you've played a level, and prioritize levels in which you're not performing well yet (because apparantly you still have a lot to learn in those). This could, for instance, be done with a Multi-Armed Bandit strategy such as UCB1, where you use the negative recent performance as a "reward".

It may also be worth looking into the Learning track of the General Video Game AI competition (http://gvgai.net/). I believe that competition has precisely the setup you mentioned of three training levels plus two levels per game for evaluation (maybe this is even where your question came from?). You can have a look at what various participants in this competition are doing if their source code is available, and/or look up literature about the competition / competing entries.